# Traveling Wave Solution of the non-linear diffusion equation - Similarity solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm working on problems in the PDE book by Evans. In Chapter 4, question no 3 is as follows:

Find explicit formulas for $v$ and $\sigma $, so that $u(x,t):= v(x-\sigma t)$ is a traveling wave solution of the nonlinear diffusion equation
\begin{equation}
 u_{t}-u_{xx} = f(u),
\end{equation} where
\begin{equation}
 f(z) = -2z^{3}+3z^{2}-z.
\end{equation}
Assume $\lim_{s \to \infty} v =1$, $\lim_{s \to - \infty}v = 0$, $\lim_{s \to \pm \infty}v’=0$.
(Hint: Multiply the equation $v'' + \sigma v’ + f(v)=0$ by $v’$ and integrate, to determine the value of $\sigma$. )

First, I tried to solve using the hint and got the following equation.

$\dfrac{(v')^2}{2}+\int \sigma \dfrac{dv}{ds}dv- \dfrac{v^4}{4}+v^3-\dfrac{v^2}{2} = constant$.
I don't know how to proceed after this.

Also, I tried to get the solution considering the homogeneous part separately and then move to the particular solution. It is also not working because here, $v$ is a function of $s$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first correct your last equation: since $f(v)=-2v^3+3v^2-v$, it should be
$$
\frac{1}{2}(v')^2+\sigma\int_{-\infty}^{s}(v')^2d\xi - \frac{1}{2}v^4 + v^3 -\frac{1}{2}v^2 = C. \tag{1}
$$
Taking the limit $s\to -\infty$ on the LHS of $(1)$ shows that $C=0$. Then, taking the limit $s\to +\infty$ we obtain
$$
\sigma\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(v')^2d\xi = 0. \tag{2}
$$
Since $v(+\infty) \neq v(-\infty)$, $v'(\xi)$ cannot be identically zero, so $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(v')^2d\xi > 0$. Therefore, $(2)$ implies $\sigma = 0$.

Having determined the values of $C$ and $\sigma$, we now return to $(1)$ to find $v(s)$:
$$
\frac{1}{2}(v')^2 - \frac{1}{2}v^4 + v^3 -\frac{1}{2}v^2 = 0 \Rightarrow
(v')^2 = v^2(v-1)^2. \tag{3}
$$
Since $v(-\infty)=0$ and $v(+\infty)=1$, we shall assume that $0<v<1$ and $v'>0$ when taking the square root of both sides of the last equation in $({3})$, so
\begin{align}
(3) \Rightarrow v'=v(1-v) &\Rightarrow \int\frac{dv}{v(1-v)}=\int ds
\Rightarrow \ln(v)-\ln(1-v) = s+c \\
&\Rightarrow v(s)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(s+c)}} \\
&\Rightarrow u(x,t)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(x-a)}}, \tag{4}
\end{align}
where $a=-c$ is an arbitrary constant. We then conclude that the "traveling wave solution" is static.